# Does anyone know what are these birds?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

Never saw them before, they appeared suddenly , the day my father died.
Place is Serbia in Europe.
Does anyone know what are these birds?[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like European Starlings (*Sturnus vulgaris*).  They are often seen in large numbers and are native to most of Europe, including Serbia.  They were [introduced to North America](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/call-of-the-reviled/) (Central Park, New York City) as a project to introduce species of birds from works of Shakespeare and are now widespread.

[image]

Source: https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/European_Starling/id